# How to test if a specific variable is present in URL query string or not?

Tags: php

I have written following php codes to catch name and email from URL query string.

```
   <?php
        $name = "rkb";                // Default name
        $email= "rkb@example.com";    // Default email
        if ($_GET['name']) {
            $name = test_input($_GET['name']);
        }
        if ($_GET['email']) {
            $email = test_input($_GET['email']);
        }

        function test_input($data) {
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
            return $data;
        }

    ?>
```

It works well when I pass variables `name` and `email` in URL. But when I load this page without query string, I get these two errors

```
Notice: Undefined index: name in path\to\folder\index.php on line 4
Notice: Undefined index: email in path\to\folder\index.php on line 7
```

I want to make the PHP to behave such that `$name` and `$email` get default values when query string is absent.

Comment: Try using a [**ternary operator**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is PHP function [**isset**](https://www.php.net/isset).

A simple way,

```
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? test_input($_GET['name']) : "rkb";
```

Comment: `A.K.A.` [**ternary operator**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: Please remove that extra ")"

Answer (score 3):

Use `empty()`. It tests whether the variable is set and whether it contains a non-null value.

```
    if (!empty($_GET['name'])) {
```

Comment: What is the difference between isset() and !empty()? Is !empty() is better as it also tests for non-null value?

Answer (score 2):

Use `if (isset($_GET['name']))` instead of `if ($_GET['name'])`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `isset()` to determine if a variable is set and is not NULL.  Also, check the `empty()` as well

```
    if (isset($_GET['name']) && !empty($_GET['name'])) {
       $name = test_input($_GET['name']); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

use isset function to check $_GET is set or not. change your code like this.

```
<?php
    $name = "rkb";                // Default name
    $email= "rkb@example.com";    // Default email
    if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
        $name = test_input($_GET['name']);
    }
    if (isset($_GET['email'])) {
        $email = test_input($_GET['email']);
    }

    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }

?>
```